# Add functionality to all Eclipse TextEditors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to add some functionality to eclipse text editors. The goal is to get a Graphics Context or add a SWT Canvas to any and all Eclipse AbstractTextEditors and package these modifications within a plug-in (so by installing the plugin I provide, the editor modification will work for the Java Editor, XML Editor, plain text editor, etc.). Are there any extension points that would suffice for this purpose, or is my best bet with a fragment? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the source code for AbstractTextEditor to see if an extension point exists for this purpose. If an extension point exists, it will be evident in that class source.

I would wager that such extension point does not exist. You are left with opening an enhancement request and in the meantime patching the plugin containing AbstractTextEditor plugin to alter the source of that file. A fragment isn't going to do the trick. Another alternative to consider is to learn and apply a bytecode weaving framework such as AspectJ (http://eclipse.org/ajdt/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been looking into AspectJ and the Reflection package to make this work. Since this seems outside the scope of my question, perhaps I should rephrase it into something I think you could answer better: "If an extension point exists, it will be evident in that class source." How is it evident? What is the syntax or signature used for defining extension points?

Comment: Extension point processing is plain Java code. There isn't necessarily a specific code pattern to search for especially since processing of extension point is delegated to another class. I would recommend looking for the place where the top-level editor canvas is constructed and see what that routine does. If it does hand-off to an extension point somewhere in that, you will see it in the body of that routine.

Comment: Have you considered contributing a separate view that interacts with the editor rather than trying to modify editor canvas? Similar to how properties and javadoc views (among others) behave. This would be a much easier path as all the necessary API exists and there should be samples to look at.